# Django reverse accessor clash - multiple uses of a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have two models, Photo and Story. The Story model uses the Photo a couple different ways - for a thumbnail, a header photo, and a gallery. I am storing an optional Story reference in the Photo model. This was causing a `E.304` error:
`(fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'stories.Story.header_image' clashes with reverse accessor for 'stories.Story.thumbnail'.`
I added `related_name='+'` to both the `thumbnail` and `header_image` fields. This disallows the backward relation and got rid of my reverse accessor clash issue. I was able to set up a `PhotoInline` in the Django admin, but also realized that there is now no way for a user to add a `thumbnail` or `header_image` inline - the typical "edit" and "add" options aren't available. What do I need to change about my models or admin config to allow for that? I tried changing the `related_name` params to name the relationships instead of disallowing them, but that didn't seem to help - not sure if I would need to use those values somewhere.

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey('Photo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')
    header_image = models.ForeignKey('Photo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='+')

    content = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]
        verbose_name = 'Story'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Stories'

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='', blank=True)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["timestamp"]
        verbose_name = 'Photo'
```

Comment: adding an actual related_name should solve the problem. Did you get the same error after you had made the change?

Comment: I no longer get the error after making that change, e.g. `thumbnail = models.ForeignKey('Photo', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='story_thumbnail')`. But in the admin, I'm only getting an empty dropdown on my Add Story page next to "Thumbnail" and "Header image" because there are no instances of the Photo model. Is there a way to make that dropdown allow the user to add a new Photo?

Answer (score 0):

Solved - I didn't register the Photo class as an AdminModel so there was no way for Django to display it as an add option to the ForeignKey reference. Didn't catch it earlier as apparently it doesn't need to be registered for Inlines to work.